# How to insert record into a dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe (df1) which has 50 columns, the first one is a cust_id and the rest are features. I also have another dataframe (df2) which contains only cust_id. I'd like to add one records per customer in df2 to df1 with all the features as 0. But as the two dataframe have two different schema, I cannot do a union. What is the best way to do that?

I use a full outer join but it generates two cust_id columns and I need one. I should somehow merge these two cust_id columns but don't know how.

Comment: Uhhm, what have you tried?

Comment: nothing comes to my mind !

Comment: maybe a full outer join helps?

Comment: H.Z., I don't know either :/ (However, notice that I didn't downvote). Good luck!

Comment: @H.Z. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to achieve something like that by doing a full outer join like the following:

```
val result = df1.join(df2, Seq("cust_id"), "full_outer")
```

However, the features are going to be `null` instead of 0. If you really need them to be zero, one way to do it would be:

```
val features = df1.columns.toSet - "cust_id" // Remove "cust_id" column
val newDF = features.foldLeft(df2)(
  (df, colName) => df.withColumn(colName, lit(0))
)
df1.unionAll(newDF)
```